# Using sub-repo with hgwebdir difficulties in mercurial

Tags: apache, mercurial

Allright I got myself in a deadlock with Mercurial and sub-repos... Here's what happenend:
I had a large mercurial repo that I server via apache and hgweb.cgi.
Due to the size of the repo I decided to move to sub-repositories and share these with hgwebdir.cgi.

Using the convert tool with the filemap option I created several sub-repositories:

```
/main/foo
/main/bar
```

Nicely created an entry for the sub-repositories in .hgsub:

```
foo = foo
bar = bar
```

And set hgwebdir.cgi up to show $/** as the root folder.

Now when I went to my site (foo.com/hg) I saw my sub-repositories with one empty reposory among them (no name, no content), but I could not download it (archive location unknown):
[empty_repo http://img707.imageshack.us/img707/8237/emptysubrepo.png](http://img707.imageshack.us/img707/8237/emptysubrepo.png)

That was allright until I added a new sub-repository.
I could not push the new .hgsub file to foo.com/hg, since that page is served by hgwebdir.

The only method I can work currently is switch from hgwebdir to hgweb, commit .hgsubste and switch back to hgwebdir.

Does someone have a good setup for such a mess?

Answer (score 0):

From what I've read on https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/PublishingRepositories#multiple

- The keys (on the left) and the values (on the right) are both filesystem paths
- The keys should be prefixes of the values and are "subtracted" from the values in order to generate the URL paths to each repository

What I'm guessing happened is that in your hgweb(dir) configuration you're specifying the same value for a collection possibly as the key, so during subtraction it ends up with a blank name and no way to get to it.

When I use [collections] to set /a/full/path = /a/full/path directly to a repo, it'll end up blank too, because it's reading that folder as a repo because it is a repo, instead of each sub-directory being an individual repo, after I removed the .hg folder and .hgsubs and everything from the root of my collection entry, all the subfolders started showing up properly.

I originally used in [paths], /path/to/my/project = /path/to/my/project, and since that is a single referenced repository, it'll subtract the value from the key, leaving you once again with '', instead I used project = /path/to/my/project and it came out as 'project'.

Hopefully that URL or these descriptions will get you out of your pickle!

Answer (score 0):

On the webserver your main and its subrepos should appear as siblings -- not with the subrepos inside main.

- Main
- ASCII
- AlignDistribute

And the URLs in your `.hgsub` should look like:

```
ASCII = ../ASCII
AlignDistribute = ../AlignDsitribute
```

Then you'll be able to push/pull to `http://foo.com/hg/Main` and when you clone it the clone/update will automatically attach and clone down the separate subrepos.